# How to run exe when system starts - not using start up folder or a task scheduler

Tags: vb.net

```
Dim wshShell As New WshShellClass()
Dim shortcut As IWshRuntimeLibrary.IWshShortcut
Dim startUpFolderPath As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Startup)

' Create the shortcut
shortcut = DirectCast(wshShell.CreateShortcut((startUpFolderPath & Convert.ToString("\")) + Application.ProductName + ".lnk"), IWshRuntimeLibrary.IWshShortcut)

shortcut.TargetPath = Application.ExecutablePath
shortcut.WorkingDirectory = Application.StartupPath
'shortcut.Description = "Launch My Application"
'shortcut.IconLocation = Application.StartupPath + @"\App.ico";
shortcut.Save()
```

Comment: What is your question and how is your code related to C#?

Comment: Welcome to [so]. What is the question? Please put effort in when asking here, see [ask]

Comment: Explain what you've tried with the code (it is unclear at the time this comment written). Are you want to convert it or finding certain errors there? Check if your question is properly written by visiting [[ask]].

Comment: See msdn : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Actually, I'm trying to run my Windows applications exe when my system starts. but without using following way 1.dont use edit registry 2.copy shortcut into Startup folder 3.service 4.schedule task into task scheduler apart from these 4 if any way that I can be done these...?                                       i have try all 4 ways that working fine but don't wana go with that way .

Comment: @ Romano Zumbé  I'm working in vb dot net so above code is in vb.net and that code directly create shortcut into the startup folder

Comment: Nope. Dont think so. You've just listed about every way to execute a program apart from clicking on a desktop icon.